# Access Doctrine Entity Manager in custom Twig Extension in ZF2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, twig, twig-extension

I am using ZfcTwig module from https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcTwig

Reference used: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

Using above link, I was able to create a custom Twig Extension. In this class, I want to access the Entity Manager to fetch some data from database.

I am registering the custom extension via following code in module.config.php -

```
'zfctwig' => array(
    'extensions' => array(
        'Application\Extension\MyCustomTwigExtension'
    )
)
```

But as I want to access a Doctrine Entity Manager in this class, I tried by creating a closure -

```
'zfctwig' => array(
    'extensions' => array(
        'Application\Extension\MyCustomTwigExtension' => function($sm) {
            $entityManager = $sm->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
            $ext = new Application\Extension\MyCustomTwigExtension();
            $ext->setEntityManager($entityManager);
            return $ext;
        },
    )
),
```

And this gives the error message as -

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Twig_Environment::addExtension() must implement interface Twig_ExtensionInterface, instance of Closure given....
```

I have tried for same via factory -

```
'zfctwig' => array(
    'extensions' => array(
        'Application\Extension\MyCustomTwigExtension' => 'Application\Extension\MyCustomTwigExtensionFactory'
    )
),
```

Error message -

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Twig_Environment::addExtension() must implement interface Twig_ExtensionInterface, instance of Application\Extension\MyCustomTwigExtensionFactory given...
```

Any ideas on injecting dependency into twig extension? It may not be just Entity Manager but access to View Helpers, etc.

**Edit:** Contents of `MyCustomTwigExtension` file -

```
namespace Application\Extension;

class MyCustomTwigExtension extends \Twig_Extension {

    protected $_eventManager;

    public function setEntityManager($eventManager = null) {
        $this->_eventManager = $eventManager;
    }

    public function getEntityManager() {
        return $this->_eventManager;
    }

    public function getFilters() {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('list', array($this, 'listFilter')),
        );
    }

    public function listFilter($content = '') {
        $repository = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('Application\Entity\User');
        $models = $repository->findAll();

        $html = '<ul>List Extension';
        foreach ($models as $model) {
            $html .= "<li>" . $model->getId() . ' ' . $model->getFullname() . "</li>";
        }
        $html .= '</ul>';

        return $html;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'list_extension';
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You instantiate `Application\Extension\MyCustomTwigExtension`. But this object is of the wrong type. Can you please show the contents of the `Application\Extension\MyCustomTwigExtension` class you are using?

Comment: Isn't it `Application\Extension\MyCustomTwigExtension` instead of `Application\Extension\MyCustomTwigExtensionFactory`?

Comment: I used the above added file when I registered it like `'zfctwig' => array('extensions' => array(      'Application\Extension\MyCustomTwigExtension'))`

Comment: Now when I register via `'Application\Extension\MyCustomTwigExtension' => 'Application\Extension\MyCustomTwigExtensionFactory'`, it gives the error `Argument 1 passed to Twig_Environment::addExtension() must implement interface Twig_ExtensionInterface, instance of Application\Extension\MyCustomTwigExtensionFactory given...`

Comment: When I register via a closure then it says the Argument 1 must implement interface Twig_ExtensionInterface but a closure is given.

Comment: Something new on this?

Answer (score 0):

The only problem you have is the following:

As mentioned in [module.config.php#32](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcTwig/blob/master/config/module.config.php#L32) you cann add Extension via Factory, but the given namespace `Application\Extension\MyCustomTwigExtensionFactory` must exist as key in your `service_manager`-config.

So you could do the following:

```
'zfctwig' => array(
    'extensions' => array(
        'customTwig' => 'MyCustomTwigExtensionFactory'
    )
),
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'MyCustomTwigExtensionFactory' => 'Application\Extension\MyCustomTwigExtensionFactory'
    )
)
```

And everything should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `ServiceLocatorAwareInterface`:

```
class MyCustomTwigExtension extends \Twig_Extension implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface {

}
```

for implementation you can use trait: ServiceLocatorAwareTrait
and you can add method to get entity manager:

```
public function getEntityManager() {
    if($this->entityManager === null) {
        $this->entityManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get(''doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default'')
    }
    return $this->entityManager;
}
```

and last thing: in configuration you should add:

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'MyCustomTwigExtensionFactory' => function() { return new MyCustomTwigExtension(); }
    )
)
```